# How to escape a % sign in a configobj value?

Tags: python, escaping, interpolation

I'd like to use both parse time and runtime interpolation for values of a [configobj](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/configobj.html) configuration file. The easiest way to do simple string interpolation in Python is `"%(foo)s" % somedict`. Unfortunately configobj uses the same interpolation mechanism and I have not yet found a way to escape it. Ideally my value would look like:

```
othervar = foo
someconfigobjkey = %(othervar)s %%(runtimevar)s
```

However configobj tries (and fails) to replace the second variable. Another way to answer this question is to provide a different (configobj) way to do both parse time and runtime interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New version of the answer:

You could use "".format() (Python 2.6 or above) or string.Template (Python 2.4 or above) for the runtime interpolation -- both of which would eliminate the conflict.

(The old version assumed the use of the standard ConfigParser module, hence the comments.)

Comment: As I stated in my initial question I use configobj and not ConfigParser. Maybe I assumed this module to be known too far anyway it can be found at http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/configobj.html.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know that module and did not recognize it as a module name in your post either.  Any reason not to just use the standard ConfigParser module?  If this would do for you as well, the problem would also be solved :)

Comment: In corporate development choice of tools is not always given.

Comment: Maybe you could use string.Template or "".format() instead of % substitution for the tuntime interpolation -- this would eliminate the conflict.

Comment: Your last proposal makes up a full new answer, that works as well as `interpolation="template"`.

Answer (score 12):

Things may have changed since this question was posted, but I've discovered that you can escape using the '%' char. This worked for me in Python 3.

In my config.ini file:

```
[LOGGING]
format = %%(asctime)-15s %%(message)s
```

In my python script file:

```
import configparser

# Load configuration
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")

log_config = config['LOGGING']

print(log_config['format']) # prints out '%(asctime)-15s %(message)s'
```

Hope it helps someone in the future (:

Comment: This question is about configobj, which happens to be different from configparser. That may be a reason for switching from configobj to configparser though.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, unfortunately configobj does not follow normal standard Python formatting rules, so `%%`, which would otherwise be the correct way to escape a percent sign, fails. Seems like a bit of a design flaw to me.

The only way I can think of to have a literal `%(foo)s` sequence in a configobj value would be to ensure part of that sequence is itself generated by a replacement:

```
>>> import configobj
>>> c= configobject.ConfigObj()
>>> c['foo']= 'bar'
>>> c['pc']= '%'
>>> c['v']= '%(foo)s %(pc)s(foo)s'
>>> c['v']
'bar %(foo)s'
```

Answer (score 3):

Digging deeper in the documentation I found a solution that fits better than the one proposed by bobince: Use a different interpolation engine, such as `interpolation="template"`. It has two advantages.

1. Does not interfere with % signs.
2. Supports escaping. (`$$` gets interpolated to `$`.)

The example would look like:

```
othervar = foo
someconfigobjkey = $othervar %(runtimevar)s
```

Comment: This is the method to use! Note that `cfg = configobj.ConfigObj(…, interpolation='template')` seems to have no effect on validation and a later `cfg.validate(…)` will still fail. What works is to change the default interpolator by setting `configobj.DEFAULT_INTERPOLATION = 'template'`. This works in both Python 2 and Python 3.

Answer (score 3):

Try using '%'+'(foo)s'.  That worked for me when dealing with ConfigParser.